# CreateExecutable returns $Failed

Tags: compile, interface

My platform is win10 64b, *Mathematica* 11 and Visual Studio 2015. When I apply `CreateExecutable`, it always returns `$Failed`. The configuration is right. Please what is the problem? Thank you.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
hello = CreateExecutable["
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
    printf(\"hello world\\n\");
  }
  ", "hello"]

(* Out: $Failed *)

In[6]:= CCompilers[]

Out[6]= {{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
  "Compiler" -> 
   CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> 
   "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0", 
  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}

In[3]:= DefaultCCompiler[]

Out[3]= CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler
```

Thank you for your suggestion. The error message is as follows.Please where is the VS Common Tools folder. The version is VS 2015 Community and install at D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

```
call "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64


cl.exe /O2 /MT  /I "d:\Program Files\Mathematica\SystemFiles\IncludeFiles\C" /I "d:\Program Files\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\include" "C:\Users\sshss\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-desktop-q8futab-15460-14760-6\hello.c" /link  user32.lib kernel32.lib gdi32.lib  /LIBPATH:"d:\Program Files\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\lib" /LIBPATH:"d:\Program Files\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64"    /out:"C:\Users\sshss\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-desktop-q8futab-15460-14760-6\hello.exe"


C:\Users\sshss\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-desktop-q8futab-15460-14760-6>call "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

You are right. The cl.exe could not work in Command Prompt. What happen? I installed Visual Studio Community according to the default. Thank you

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sshss>cl.exe
'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\sshss>
```

Comment: Are there error messages?  Add the options `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print`.

Comment: Based on your update, it is possible that the Visual Studio installation on your computer is damaged or incomplete. Can you use cl.exe from a command line?  There should be a start menu entry that opens a command window where cl.exe can be used. Does it work correctly?  Are you sure that the command line tools for C++ compilation are installed?

Comment: Is there a registry entry for this key? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7`